# How to instantiate a session scoped bean without creating a reference to it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket

I have a websocket scoped bean that do something everytime that a new session is created. The problem is that this bean use some observable handlers, it's not called directly, so the bean is never instantiated.

How do I instantiate a websocket scoped bean without making a direct acces to it?

Comment: Redesign as it smells from miles away. If it is not instantioned, than it is "not scoped" at all so it can be singleton as well.

Comment: The bean uses session information to filter data for specific users and send the filtered data to them.

Comment: And what is the problem? You can use session bean in application scoped bean.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Create an interface to use on the components that you want to be initialized:

```
public interface WebSocketSessionPrematureInitialization {
    default void initialize() {}
}
```

Create a component to initialize all the components that implements the interface:

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = "websocket", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class WebSocketBeanInitializer {

    private final List<? extends WebSocketSessionPrematureInitialization> wsInit;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketBeanInitializer(List<? extends WebSocketSessionPrematureInitialization> wsInit) {
        this.wsInit = wsInit;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        for (WebSocketSessionPrematureInitialization bean : wsInit)
            bean.initialize();
    }

}
```

Now you just need to call the initialize() method of the WebSocketBeanInitializer always that a new session is created.